# R gamlss::predict.gamlss not an exported object from 'namespace:gamlss'

Tags: r, function, gamlss

I am experiencing some confusing behavior from `gamlss` in R. The documentation lists predict.gamlss and `?predict.gamlss` returns the function documentation in RStudio. However, the function does not autocomplete when typing out `predict.gamlss`, and trying to run it returns `Error: 'predict.gamlss' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gamlss'`. How does that happen? Is the function deactivated somehow? There is a separate function `predictAll` that does work.

The documentation does state

> This function is under development

I am trying to access the function because I am experiencing some confusing results with `predict` and `predictAll`.

R version is 4.0.0. `gamlss` version is 5.1.6.

Comment: What version R and gamlss do you use? And can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, what you describe is expected and is normal S3 method dispatching. The method `predict.gamlss` is called when you call `predict` on a object of class `gamlss`.

Consider the following (from the documentation of `?predict.gamlss`)

```
data(abdom)
aa <- gamlss(y ~ cs(x^.5), data = abdom)
#[1] 371.3931
predict(aa)[610]
```

Looking at the class of `aa`:

```
class(aa)
#[1] "gamlss" "gam"    "glm"    "lm"
```

The function is not exported, but the S3 method is registered.

As to the difference between `predictAll` and `predict.gamlss`, you'll have to read the documentation (the two are documented together). My guess is that `predictAll` predict all listed in the `what`-argument of `predict.gamlss`.

Comment: You're correct. The function is fine but my understanding of the details is not. I have posted a related [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464943/r-gamlss-fitting-and-simulating-lognormal-response) to cross validated to figure that out.